# Best way to start a program at boot on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, boot, startup

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 11.10 and I have some programs I want to start at boot time such as Nginx, my Unicorn workers etc.

In fact, I know how to start my programmes either by adding a script to /etc/init.d/ or to /etc/init/ via Startup.

What I want to know is if there is a "good way" or "best way" to do it.
Maybe there is a more sustainable way considering the future evolutions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all things Linux, there are a bunch of different ways to do this.

The best way, though, is to write [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) files for the apps you need to start on boot. Upstart replaces the legacy sysV init system.

Comment: The real question is, how did he manage to install nginx without getting an init script?

Comment: When you install Nginx via apt, you get a nginx file in /etc/init.d/. I just removed it and replaced it with a file in /etc/init/.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is make a copy of /etc/init.d/skeleton and adjust it to my needs. It's quite simple and I think it's the best way to implement starting up things at boot time. Don't forget to run "update-rc.d name-of-app defaults" or something similar to enable it.

Alternatively you can edit /etc/rc.local to your needs. No need to run update-rc.d in that case.